# Python flask application after docker-compose up is okay, open localhost:5000, get `The connection was reset`

Tags: python, docker, flask, wsgi

In docker-compose.yml ,

```
services:
  app:
    build: .
    entrypoint: ["python", "wsgi.py"]
      
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:5000:5000
```

In wsgi.py:

```
from app import app as application

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```

the docker build is successful, after run `docker-compose up`,  the terminal shows `Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)`, but when open the link, it says `The connection was reset`, why? how to fix it? Thanks. (I have checked my firewall, there is no blocker)

Comment: What happens if you use host='127.0.0.1'?  Sometimes "localhost" and '0.0.0.0' mean different things.

Comment: @Frank Yellin, it is still the same.

Comment: It looks like your `host='0.0.0.0'` doesn't work, since the log says `Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/`. Are you sure you're running the latest version of the code? Try building the image again using `docker-compose build`.

Comment: Yes, after rebuild, it works. Thanks